# sed error: unterminated 's' command

Tags: unix, sed

I run below sed command

```
sed -i s/abc=.*$/abc=def ghi/g hpq_sf_attach_wf_param.txt
```

and it gave me error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unterminated `s' command
```

I noticed it is due to space in between of `def` and `ghi`.
Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with sed unterminated s command in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31277018/error-with-sed-unterminated-s-command-in-bash)

Answer (score 16):

You need to use quoting to protect special characters, including spaces, `$`, and `*`.

```
sed -i 's/abc=.*$/abc=def ghi/g' hpq_sf_attach_wf_param.txt
```

Comment: hi , adding single quote caused the update to failed, nothing is changing within the target file hpq_sf_attach_wf_param.txt ~ although it should have been updated

Comment: Are you sure your pattern is correct then?  Perhaps edit your question to include some sample lines from `hpq_sf_attach_param.txt`?

Answer (score 5):

So geekosaur had it right. The the reason you had the problem though is because it needs to be double quotes for the wildcards because with single quotes it takes them as literal characters, not for the meaning you want.

```
sed -i "s/abc=.*$/abc=def ghi/g" hpq_sf_attach_wf_param.txt
```

Also if the space between "def" and "ghi" gives you problems, adding a "\" should help making it read it as a literal space.

```
sed -i "s/abc=.*$/abc=def\ ghi/g" hpq_sf_attach_wf_param.txt
```

Comment: This explanation makes absolutely no sense: "it needs to be double quotes for the wildcards because with single quotes it takes them as literal characters". The only relevant shell metacharacter in the string is `$`, and `$/` is not a valid shell variable so is left untouched. Consider: `echo "s/abc=.*$/abc=def ghi/g"|md5sum; echo 's/abc=.*$/abc=def ghi/g'|md5sum`. If there was a difference, why is md5sum output identical? Also, `\ ` does absolutely nothing useful.

Comment: can someone suggest me what is going wrong here - sed -i "s|##CONNECTION_DETAILS##|${CONNECTION_DETAILS}|g" dep.yaml. The value of CONNECTION_DETAILS is in encoded form CSAgewogICAgICAgICJjb25uZWN0aW9uX25hbWVfMSI6ICJPRlNBQV9BTkFMWVRJQ1NfUFVCIiwK ICAgICAgICAiZGF0YWJhc2VfbmFtZV8xIjogIk9GU0FBX0FOQUxZVElDU19QVUIiLAogICAgICAg ICJiaV9TZXJ2aWNlc18xIjpbImR2IiwicnBkIiwiYmlwdWJsaXNoZXIiXQogICAgICB9Cg==