# Error with sed unterminated s command in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I'm having a problem with using sed in a bash script.
Here is the line:

```
sed -i "s/"$name"/"$input"/g" ~/input.script
```

I'm getting this error:
         sed: -e expression #1, char 24: unterminated `s' command

Weirdly enough it was working in an earlier version of my code. I've been trouble shooting but I cannot find a solution.

Comment: Your variables probably have a newline or slash in them which is confusing sed.

Comment: @EtanReisner I'm an idiot. That ended up being the error. There was a space in the variable.

Comment: A space only causes a problem with unquoted variables. So if you removed them like Eugeniu Rosca said then the problem should have gone away. A newline would still be a problem though as would a slash.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed/29626460#29626460

Answer (score 6):

You don't need nested quotes. Also, try changing the delimeter:

```
sed -i "s@$name@$input@g" ~/input.script
```

Comment: The use of `@` here is to allow `/` in the variable values without a problem. It trades the problem for `@` in the variable values. So you need to pick something that cannot be in your input to do this correctly.

Comment: @Etan Reisner: Yep, I am aware of it :) Still thanks for mentioning. Anyways, it seems like OP solved his issue (waiting for the explanations...).

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't for you that was for the OP/etc.