# sed to remove javascript call from minified html

Tags: javascript, sed

I want to remove all external js call from minified html file. However, the following removes if js call is in another line (not works for minified html)

```
var=$(sed  -e '/^<script.*<\/script>$/d' -e '/.js/!d' testFile.html)
grep -v "$var" "testFile.html" | sponge "testFile.html"
```

Sample input file:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>JavaScript Ders 2</title> <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" language="javascript"></script> <script></script> </head><body></body></html>
```

Sample output file:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>JavaScript Ders 2</title> <script></script> </head><body></body></html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: with linux command line you mean?

Comment: I want to create a linux shell script for that

Comment: Veeeery similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51362345/3266847 did you create a new account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately sed doesn't support non-greedy/lazy match (easily). Try perl:

```
 perl -pe 's/<script.*?script> //'
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I want to also check it contains .js in this match. How can I do that?