# Sed match N times

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I wanna remove a specific argument from a command like the one below,

```
mycommand --address=127.0.0.1 --file=/usr/local/somefile --port=8090 --key-file=/usr/local/server.key
```

In this case, I wanna remove `--file=/usr/local/somefile`, how can I match the text from `--file=` to the next `--` or to the N times occurrences of `--` using `sed`.

Comment: Post your efforts in to the question, even if they aren't solving your use-case. That way, we'll know the efforts you made.

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382304/sed-to-remove-javascript-call-from-minified-html/51397354#51397354

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/--file=\S\+\s\?//' file
```

This removes the string beginning `--file=` and ending in one or non-space characters followed by an optional space.

```
sed -r 's/((--\S+\s?){3})--\S+\s?/\1/' file
```

This removes the fourth string beginning with `--` followed by one or more non-space characters followed by a possible space. The fourth occurrence is found by grouping the first three such string and then another and replacing the match by the group.

The reverse of the above can be achieved by using:

```
sed '/\n/!s/--\S\+/\n&\n/g;/^--file=/P;D' file
```

This splits each line into string beginning with `--` and printing the one(s) that begin `--file=`.

```
sed '/\n/!s/--\S\+/\n&\n/g;/^--/{x;s/^/x/;/^x\{3\}$/{x;P;x};x};D' file
```

This would extract the third option.

```
sed '/\n/!s/--\S\+/\n&\n/g;/^--/{x;s/^/x/;/^x\{2,3\}$/{x;P;x};x};D' file
```

This would extract the second and third options.

Answer (score 1):

If `awk` is an option, try this:

```
awk '{gsub(/--file=[^ ]+/, ""); print }'
```

From your input:

```
echo "mycommand --address=127.0.0.1 --file=/usr/local/somefile --port=8090 --key-file=/usr/local/server.key" \
| awk '{gsub(/--file=[^ ]+/, ""); print }'
```

Will output:

```
mycommand --address=127.0.0.1  --port=8090 --key-file=/usr/local/server.key
```

Comment: Try it on the original command. It will eat the `--port` option as well because `.*` is greedy. And on top of that, it won't work when `--file` is the last option.

Comment: @PesaThe thanks for the heads up, giving a try with `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the command -

1) this fulfills the first requirement - where it removes the required text from a pattern using Sed

```
echo "mycommand --address=127.0.0.1 --file=/usr/local/somefile --port=8090 --key-file=/usr/local/server.key" | sed -e "s/\([[:space:]]\)[[:space:]]*/\1/g" | sed -e "s/\(.*\)--file=[[:alnum:]\/]*\(.*\)/\1\2/"

mycommand --address=127.0.0.1  --port=8090 --key-file=/usr/local/server.key
```

Note: if it would have been Python, it is an easy go with Non-greedy regular expression which is unavailable in Sed

Comment: For correct formatting, use 4 spaces at the front of lines that are code/output/error messages OR you can highlight code with mouse and then use the `{}` tool on the edit menu. Finally, maybe you can wrap you code to a second line, so it won't require scrolling to the right to view your solution. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Bash has substitutions built in.

```
bash$ set -- mycommand --address=127.0.0.1 --file=/usr/local/somefile --port=8090 --key-file=/usr/local/server.key

bash$ echo "${@/--file=\/usr\/local\/somefile/}"
mycommand --address=127.0.0.1  --port=8090 --key-file=/usr/local/server.key
```

For a more robust solution, you probably want to convert the command line into an array instead.